# form is not shown despite being nested to company model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

The use case of the app I am trying to develop is about registering the company who are interested for franchise. I have taken this concept from [franchisebazar](https://www.franchisebazar.com/franchisor-registration/) for learning purpose. There i saw company info, brand info and business model for registering the company. That is why I created the following model. I want the create and update view now so from the frontend i can hit the api request to create and update. I designed the following `serializer` and `APIView`. However, when i try to test in the browser, if the coded way is working or not, i could not see the form for brand and business model despite they are nested in company. Thus, I want to know if i have to extend it more by creating a view for brand and business model separately or i did something wrong in my code.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)


class Brand(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    website = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)


class BusinessModel(models.Model):


    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_business_model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, related_name='industry', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    segments = models.ForeignKey(Segment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    total_investment = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TOTAL_INVESTMENT, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.name


class CompanyView(views.APIView):

    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        reply = {}
        try:
            companies = Company.objects.all()
            if pk:
                company = companies.get(pk=pk)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(company).data
            reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(companies, many=True).data
        except Company.DoesNotExist:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)


    def post(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        reply = {}
        company={}
        if pk is not None:
            try:
                company = Company.object.get(pk=pk)
            except Company.DoesNotExist:
                return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(instance=company, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            serialized_data.save(owner=request.user)
        else:
            return error.ValidationError(serialized_data.errors).as_response()
        reply['data'] = serialized_data.data
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    company_brand = BrandSerializer(many=True)
    company_business_model = BusinessModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:

        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason why you don't see the form which allows you update brand and business model instances is because the default behaviour of model serializer doesn't allow you to do that. You need to write your own custom update method in your serializer to save the changes made to the brand and business instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, only update method will work and no need to create separate brand and business model view then?

Comment: You can only update company instances at this point. You can use only one view if you want (and customise the serializer and possibly the view as well to update brand and business model instances) though I think it's more inline with RESTful convention to create separate endpoints for each model instance you need to update. Hopefully someone else can help you with the update all 3 instances part. I've never done it myself and still pretty new to this framework.